# How to run effective few tasks in java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a case to run some tasks (15-20) every 5ms. It will be simple select to db, parsing data and save in my db.

I have a spring boot application, java8.
I have a problem because I don't know how to do it effectively.
It should works 24/7 and never stop.
I found 2-3 solutions like Timer, but it should run every few ms, separetly so let me know if you have any better idea.

Comment: We need a bit more details.  Can your database handle 8000 requests/second (20 tasks X 200 requests a second X 2 (one read, one write))?  Can your network handle this?  For the code, I would have a thread per task with a loop that does a `Thread.sleep(5)` and a `ThreadGroup` to restart dead threads.  No need for anything Spring related.

Comment: Performence of db it's not my problem. I have to so I have to send select every few ms to DB and save in my. So create few Threads lor using Thread Pool Service will be effective?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to handle it will be with micro services architecture.

send the tasks in message queue like kafka and deploy your spring application on multiple machines.

The application will listen to the queue and handle the jobs.

If the DB is the bottleneck is should be shard.

Comment: Unfortunately it will be deploy as deployment on Kubernetes Cluster, so I'm not able to separate it to few micro apps.

Answer (score 0):

Enable your application for scheduling by @EnableScheduling then u can schedule your task accordingly on basis of cron expression.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * ?")
public void method() {
   // Your task
}
```

The above cron expression will make sure that every 5 mins this method will execute.

Comment: That would be great if the OP wanted every 5 minutes but they want every 5 *milliseconds*.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

```java
// prepare list of tasks
List<Runnable> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

tasks.add(() -> {
    System.out.println("I am task 1");
});
tasks.add(() -> {
    System.out.println("I am task 2");
});
// ... and so on

// Schedule each task to launch every 5 ms
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(tasks.size());

tasks.forEach(task -> {
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
});
```

**Option 2**

```java
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 0, fixedDelay = 5)
public void task1() {
   // do stuff
}

@Scheduled(initialDelay = 0, fixedDelay = 5)
public void task2() {
   // do stuff
}

// and so on
```